# How to compare object parameter to another object parameter (inside array)

Tags: java, object

What do I need to write inside the " if " statement in order to check if the object's variable (number) is equal to any of the object's variables (number) inside my array?

```
public class Question{

    private int number;
    private String questionString;
    private int index = 0;

    public Question(int number, String questionString){


if(number < 0){
        System.out.print("Number cannot be negative!");
    }
    if(questionString.equals(null) || questionString.trim().isEmpty()){
        System.out.print("Question cannot be empty!");
    }

        this.number = number;
        this.questionString = questionString;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
            if(o instanceof Question){  
               for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                   if(.... ){

                   }
               }
                return true;
            }
            return false;   
        }


}
```

Test Class (main Class), ofc not yet completed I just hope it gives you enough information, on how to proceed on my Question class:

```
public class Test{
        String name;
        Question[] questions;

        public Testi(String name, int nrQuestions){

        }

        public static void main(String[]args){

        }

}
```

Comment: simply write `return number == (Question)o.getNumber()` check the questions in the array for equiality

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that, and also do I remove the if statement completely or what?

Comment: do you want to check if a number inside an array already exists, or what are you trying to achive?

Comment: I cannot see any mathod taking an array. Could please leave out the unneccessary code (e.g. `equals`, `toString` and show us the code that matters (especially from the test method)?

Comment: Please keep Java conventions, i.e. `getquestionString()` -> `getQuestionString()` etc

Comment: There you go guys, did some editing hope this is enough.. to get my point through. 
Once again I will use the equals method in the Test class, so I want to test if an object of Question already exists inside the array before I let the user  add it. (I.e 2 questions are the same if their number is the same")

Comment: @KevinEsche Yes I am, check the Question to be added number value with the already existing Objects ( number value) inside the array

Comment: @Würgspaß Updated the code hope it helps to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
    public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o == null )
    return false;

    if(o instanceof Question){
        if (((Question)o).number == this.number ){
            if (this.questionString.equals(((Question)o).questionString)){
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Be careful though, if you're implementing `equals()` you should also implement `hashCode()`. It's your "model" that should make clear when two objects are equal. In your case, I would say that when two Question's `number` are the same, then the Question is also the same. If not, you should also add `questionString` to the check

Comment: I should have made more clear I think, I need to check the (Object o) with the objects inside the array and decide whether that object already exists (Object number value is the same)

Comment: ok, you should add questionString to equals then. See my updated answer

Comment: But don't I need to return a boolean expression? Also I only need to check number value. So can you please update your code accordingly I tried a few times with no success. Thanks a bunch

Comment: yes, you should return a boolean. The idea is to return true if o.number == this.number AND the two Strings are equal. Code updated

Comment: Tyvm mate,  I think this does it. I'll post my another question if I need help with any issues on the Test Class, which I hope I don't need to. Again thank you for your time and knowledge ^^

Comment: you're welcome. Remember to study the equals&Hashcode contract :)

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment, I think I now understand your REAL issue: You tried to use the `equals()` method to compare an object to an array of objects that you pass to this method, right? The call to equals would look like this:

```
Question[] questions;
question.equals(questions);
```

Technically this is possible with Java, but **strongly discouraged** I would say.  `equals()` should only be used to compare to one object at a time (and stick to the hashCode/equals contract).

So I suggest you to do something like this:

```
     //your application code
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Question){  
            return (((Question)obj).number == this.number);
        }
        return false;   
    }

    //use this to obey the equals/hashCode contract
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.number;
    }

    // your test code -------------

    public void testQuestions(Question testAgainstThisObject, Question[] testQuestions) {
        for (Question testThisQuestion : testQuestions) {
            assertTrue(testAgainstThisObject.equals(testThisQuestion));
        }
    }
```

**Another way** would be to use a specialised method in `Question.java`, something like this:

```
    public boolean isThisContained(Question[] questions) {
        for (Question question : questions) {
            if (this.equals(question)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much I would have given u the Answer but @Shine was faster, tyvm to you both though. I will update the code in another answer (would be probably better), if I get stuck'd again while implementing the Test class. Thanks a bunch again <3

Comment: @JavaMasterz If you have learned from both answers, you can mark both ansers as "helpful". Just click on the upper arrow  ;-)

Comment: I need 5 reputation or something can't upvote, otherwise I would

Comment: Ah, ok. I dont remember that hurdle. I thought you would even earn a badge. Never mind.